# Webpage showing up different hosted online compared to viewed locally

Tags: html, css

[Webpage Locally viewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnnk0.png)

Like the title states, I am working on a Homework assignment and have hit a stopping point. I viewed the page locally (as seen in attached image), and all is well. When I put the HTML and CSS onto Github and a different hosted server I get something a bit different in terms of layout, and I haven't been able to figure out why. I included a Myer's reset to begin my webpage, so I figured the layout would be universal, but am still running into issues.

Here is my webpage on Github: https://ddenio.github.io/CSS3_Websiteproject4.0/DerinCSS3_4.0/DerinfinalProject4.0.html

And on a different server: http://ddenio.byethost15.com/DerinfinalProject4.0.html

**Here is my code:**

```css
body{
  background-color: #424242;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 100%;
  
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size:300%;
  color:rgb(255,255,255);
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  text-align: left;
  
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top:25px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

h2{
  line-height: 100%;
  
  font-family: Helvetica, Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman";
  font-size:200%;
  color:#03DAC6;
  background-color:#6320EE;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 130px;
  width:99%;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius:15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #8075FF;
  border: solid 1px #080808;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

nav {
  line-height: 150%;
  background-color:#8075FF;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Georgia,Arial, "Times New Roman";
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius:15px;
  border: solid 1px #080808;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1px;
}



li {
  
  font-family: Helvetica,Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman";
  font-size:115%;
  color:rgb(0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  
}

label {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: Helvetica,Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman";
  font-size:115%;
  color:rgb(0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  

}

summary {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: Helvetica,Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman";
  font-size:115%;
  color:rgb(0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  
}

p {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: Helvetica,Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman";
  font-size:115%;
  color:rgb(0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-left:10px;
  
}

footer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  background-color:#8075FF;
  border: solid 1px #080808;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#footertext {
  
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial, Georgia, "Times New Roman";
  font-size:100%;
  color:rgb(0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}

div {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color:#03DAC6;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {

  width: 150px;
}

.animate{
  background:#03DAC6;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s,opacity 1s,background 1s,width 1s,height 1s,font-size 1s;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -o-transition-property:width,height,-o-transform,background,font-size,opacity;
  -o-transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;
  -moz-transition-property:width,height,-o-transform,background,font-size,opacity;
  -moz-transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;
  transition-property:width,height,transform,background,font-size,opacity;
  transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;
  
}

.animate:hover{
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  opacity:1;
  background:#1ec7e6;
  
}

.animate:focus{
  background:rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Derin's Final Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/Meyer_reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/html5final4.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1>Derin Eugene DeNio</h1>
        
        

            <nav>
                <h2> Links </h2>
                  <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" title="Wikipedia.org" tabindex="1" class="animate">Wiki</a>
                  <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1961_Haitian_parliamentary_election" title="1961 Haitian parliamentary election" tabindex="2" class="animate">Wiki 2</a>
                  <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_Vitti" title="Académie Vitti" tabindex="3" class="animate">Wiki 3</a>
                  <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Former_Gilead_Railroad_Station" title="Former Gilead Railroad Station" tabindex="4" class="animate">Wiki 4</a>
            </nav>
            
      </header>
      
        <section>
            <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Pizza</li>
                <li>Caprese Salad</li>
                <li>Tacos</li>
                <li>Brownies</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        
        

        <section>
            <h2>Achievements</h2>
            <div>
            <label for="course">Progress in this course (100%)</label>
            <progress id="course" value="100" max="100">100%</progress><br>
            <label for="capstone">Progress in the Specialization capstone (20%)</label>
            <progress id="capstone" value="20" max="100">20%</progress><br>
            <label for="life">Progress in life goals (45%)</label>
            <progress id="life" value="45" max="100">45%</progress>
        </div>
        </section>
        
        
        
        <section>
            <h2>More About Me</h2>
            <details>
                <summary>My Childhood</summary>
            <p>I grew up in Carlsbad, New Mexico; close to the Carlsbad Caverns!</p>
            </details>
        </section>

        

        <footer>
            <p id="footertext">
                <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png" alt="Intro to web design logo"/>
                This page was created by Derin DeNio &#38; Colleen van Lent. To learn more about web design, visit 
                <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro to Web Design</a>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any insight would be much appreciated, I thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

The css must different.

Adding this makes a big difference:

```
h2 { margin: 0; }
```

and also remove font-size on h2.

Comment: The margin:0 on h2 did the trick, as well as making the section height larger, thank you for your input!!

Comment: Click the 'up' arrow if an answer helps.